# Why does this method not change the global variable?

Tags: c#

The global variable is not changed when used as a parameter in a method. It remains the same. I would like it to change accordingly to the methods algorithm.

```
//Test
float globalBill;

public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  saveGlobalBill(globalBill);
  Console.WriteLine("Global bill now = " + globalBill); //Console returns 0
}

public void saveGlobalBill(float bill)
{
   bill += 5;
   Console.WriteLine("In method bill is " + bill); //Console returns 5
}
```

Comment: This is because the float is ValueType which cannot be changed by reference. You can pass it to the method with "ref" keyword

Comment: There are no Global Variables in C#, `globalBill` is, I'm assuming, an per-instance member (/field). Integers are "value types", when you pass them as parameters, they are copied to a variable in the called method. If you were to pass it _by reference_, you'd get the  behavior you seem to expect. Add the keyword `ref` both at the parameter declaration (`ref float bill`) and at the call site (`saveGlobalBill(ref globalBill)`)

Answer (score 7):

First of all pass your global variable as an argument by reference means just add `ref` keyword in your method signature like

```
public void saveGlobalBill(ref float bill)  //<= Notice this "ref" keyword here
{
    //Your stuff here
}
```

Then call this method from your constructor like

```
saveGlobalBill(ref globalBill);  //<= Notice this "ref" keyword here
```

**Question:** What's the role of `ref` keyword?

**Answer:** When used in a method's parameter list, the ref keyword indicates that an argument is passed by reference, not by value. The effect of passing by reference is that any change to the argument in the called method is reflected in the calling method.

That means your `bill` float parameter is treated as a reference to `globalBill`.

You can read more about `ref` keyword from [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)

Answer (score 2):

Since globalBill is a primitive type, it's passed by value, so the variable that you're changing is the variable local to the saveGlobalBill method, not the global variable (global for all intents and purposes in this case, at least, though it's local to the class containing your code).

Since it's a global variable, you don't need to pass it as an argument at all. What you're looking for is the following:

```
//Test
float globalBill;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    saveGlobalBill();
    Console.WriteLine("Global bill now = " + globalBill); //Console returns 0
}

public void saveGlobalBill()
{
    globalBill += 5;
    Console.WriteLine("In method bill is " + globalBill); //Console returns 5
}
```

Alternatively, as others say, pass it by reference, but in that case I don't see the point of declaring it as a global value in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

when you pass parameters by value methods do not effect value of themes to changing value of passed parameters you must pass theme as reference parameters.

```
//Test
float globalBill;
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  saveGlobalBill(ref globalBill);
  Console.WriteLine("Global bill now = " + globalBill); //Console returns 0
}

public void saveGlobalBill(ref float bill)
{
   bill += 5;
   Console.WriteLine("In method bill is " + bill); //Console returns 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you pass float data to parameter, ***it's copied***.

So whatever you do in the function, the value that passed by parameter wouldn't be change when you get out of the function.

Here is the way to do what you want.

***Pass the parameter using ref keyword***

```
//Test
float globalBill;

public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  saveGlobalBill(ref globalBill);
  Console.WriteLine("Global bill now = " + globalBill); //Console returns 0
}

public void saveGlobalBill(ref float bill)
{
   bill += 5;
   Console.WriteLine("In method bill is " + bill); //Console returns 5
}
```

And I recommend you to study about "call by value" and "call by reference".

I hope it helps.

Thank you. :)